# zip files contain UTF-8 content

Tags: php, file, utf-8, zip

I'm using this function to zip files.

```
function zip($path, $file){
    $zipname = getFilename($path.$file).'.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($path.$zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    $zip->addFile($path.$file,  $file);
    $zip->close();
    return $zipname;
}
```

Lately, I found that it has an error with files contain utf-8 content (filename also). The result is something similar to:

```
        Thùc hiÖn c«ng v¨n sè 775-CV/QU, ngµy 30 th¸ng 11 n¨m 2009 cña 
QuËn uû §å S¬n vÒ viÖc chuÈn bÞ b¸o c¸o t×nh h×nh
```

How could I fix it?